# What considerations would I need when configuring iptables?

Tags: security, iptables

## Synopsis

I am looking at learning more about Server Administration.  I have been running my own web server for a few years although many things were set-up by my friend and now I wish to learn more about these tasks.

I'm mainly curious about Security, Network security and firewalls and would love to find a good resource/book to learn more into this.

Nevertheless, my intentions are:

- To block all incoming connections; except specific ports
- To understand any security related tasks I need to research

I have a short list of ports to allow incoming connections for:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT            # allows anyone to ping?
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  # allow public ssh
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT  # allow public apache
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT  # allow public apache (ssl)
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9001 -j ACCEPT  # allow a public service
$ iptables -A INPUT -j DROP                      # default drop
```

My list of rules above theoretically seem secure enough to block everything except 22, 80, 443 and 9001 - but when these rules are active I cannot ssh into my server.  Then I flush the rules (`iptables -F`) and I can ssh again.

Comment: What are the services running on your server? You are not going to use `https` ?

Comment: Currently apache is not installed or running but yes I will be using https, so I believe I could do: `iptables -A INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`?  I *may* host a mail server too and other services which i can enable via the firewall.

Comment: I'm currently researching this myself. [This website](http://linoxide.com/firewall/block-common-attacks-iptables/) illustrates some attacks that you should probably be aware of.  Since you are allowing all icmp traffic, the section regarding smurf attacks is particularly relevant... I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the drop rule before the rest of the rules, then SSH should work normally.

The order is important as iptables evaluate the rules from top to bottom. In the same way if you first make a rule that allows to port 22 and then the next rule that drops everything to port 22, the latter rule applies.

Here is an example of a configuration from a working production server:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES IN:"
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES OUT:"
COMMIT
```

It first sets both input and forwarded connections to drop by default and outgoing accept by default. Then the connections with state related and established are accepted. Then ICMP is globally accepted and the loopback traffic is accepted. After that destination ports 22 and 80 are accepted, followed by rules about logging etc. Using centos I save the rules into a file so if I reload iptables it refreshes the rules from that file directly. Of course to set a default file you need to be sure the rules are working ok as they are loaded at reboot.

One can use 'iptables-restore < path_to_rules' to reload a rule set from a file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please avoid such one-line answers. We like our answers to be more comprehensive. Could you provide an example of how exactly the rules should be set? Perhaps explain why the order is important and how this solves the issue?

Comment: Well as short as the reply is, I find it quite clear. Put the drop rule before the others. The order is important as the drop rule is a generic one so it overrules the rules before it. In the same way if you first make a rule that allows to port 22 and then the next rule that drops everything to port 22, the latter rule applies.

Comment: Please [edit] instead of commenting and just add the correct commands in the right order. This has already been flagged twice as "not an answer" and "low quality" (that one was automatic because of its length). You could, for example, include the exact commands so they can be copy/pasted or include your explanation from the comment above in your actual answer. Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted with no warning.

Comment: :( this bricks my server and existing ssh connections - i will reboot the server and it will clear the rules out.  How do i apply these rules without bricking the server?

Comment: Added info to my answer.

Comment: yeah i used `iptables-restore` to import your rules and it appears to work well, thanks!  However i'm interested in understanding how you applied these rules without bricking the server (like I managed to)

Comment: The bricking occurs if you enter the rules one by one on commandline, as then you first apply the drop rule, which drops the connections immediately without you having the possibility to set the next rule which would keep the already established connections. When all rules are applied at once with commit, this doesn't occur as the complete ruleset is used instead of rule by rule.

Comment: Three things to mention: Firstly, the first rule (of the rule set at the top of your answer) should be : `iptables -P INPUT DROP` not -A, in order to set the policy, else is breaks connection as @Ash mentionned. Secondly, iptables rules are evaluated from top to bottom in the order in which they appear. There is no "generic rule that overrides previous ones". Thirdly, in your second ruleset, REJECT target is terminating target, which means you will never log anything with "IPTABLES IN:".

Comment: The first set of rules was actually put there by terdon while editing my answer, I always restore the rules from a file so I didn't check that part. You are correct that the wording there is not good, I didn't mean that it is a special rule, just that as it covers all ports it essentially disables the previous rules. Thanks for the pointer about the reject rule! I will adjust my answer to be more clear.